# Form submit in conditionally rendered component is not processed

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, conditional-rendering

I have a custom tagfile with a form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="click">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean[method]}" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

I'm conditionally rendering it by ajax as below:

```
<h:panelGroup id="test">
  <h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="click">
      <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{backingTest.updateFlag}" render=":test"/>
    </h:commandButton>
  </h:form>
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{backingTest.flag}">
    <my:customtag bean="#{backingTest}" method="printMessage"/>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This is the associated backing bean:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BackingTest {

    private boolean flag = false;

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public void updateFlag() {
        flag = true;
    }

    public boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }
}
```

When I click the first command button, then the `updateFlag()` method is properly invoked and the second command button is properly shown. But when I then click the second command button, it never hits the `printMessage()` method. In the web browser's JS console and HTTP traffic monitor I can see that the `click` event is successfully fired and that the XHR POST request is successfully being sent.

If I remove the `rendered` attribute, then everything works as expected.

How is this caused and how can I solve it? I'm using Mojarra 2.1.25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused by 2 facts:

1. When JSF needs to decode a form submit action or a submitted input value, then it also checks if the component is rendered or not (as safeguard against hacked/tampered requests).
2. Request scoped beans are recreated on every HTTP request (an ajax request counts also as one request!).

In your specific case, the `rendered` condition has evaluated `false` while JSF needs to decode the form submit action and therefore the non-rendered input/command components are never processed.

Putting the bean in view scope should fix it. Below example assumes JSF 2.x.

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
```

And below example assumes JSF 2.2+ with CDI:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

@Named
@ViewScoped
```

Or, if the techncial requirement is to keep the bean in request scope, then carry around the condition behind `rendered` attribute in a [`<o:inputHidden>`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/inputHidden). Adjust your snippet to include it in the `<h:form>`.

```
<o:inputHidden value="#{backingTest.flag}" />
```

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) - point 6
- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/7031941#7031941)

Comment: I have the similar problem. Is there any work around that you could achieve a solution with request scoped bean? As in my case, web application is already huge and the bean has to have Request scope for several other reasons.