# ajax listener inside conditionally rendered element not working

Tags: ajax, jsf

Here is a test case of my problem:

#### TestBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2329929006490721388L;

    private List<TestObject> testObjects;
    private int selectedId;

    public TestBean(){
        List<TestObject> to = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            TestObject o = new TestObject(i, "object-"+i);
            to.add(o);
        }
        this.setTestObjects(to);
    }

    public void testAjaxListener(int id){
        System.out.println("testAjaxListener("+id+")");
        this.setSelectedId(id);
    }

    //+getters/setters
}
```

#### TestObject

```
public class TestObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public TestObject(int id, String name){
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName(name);
    }

    //+getters/setters
}
```

#### Test.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="testForm">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param['view'] eq 'test'}">
            <h2>DataTable</h2>
            <h:dataTable var="o" value="#{testBean.testObjects}">
                <h:column>
                    <h:commandLink value="#{o.name}" actionListener="#{testBean.testAjaxListener(o.id)}">
                        <f:ajax
                            render=":testForm:outputTest"
                        />
                    </h:commandLink>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <h2>output</h2>
            <h:outputText id="outputTest" value="#{testBean.selectedId}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The problem is, that actionListener won't firing (i'm checking that with System.out.print as you can see). It works fine when i remove conditional render from panelGroup, so i think that is the issue - but how can i fix it?
I have readed those topics:
[h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183),
[f:ajax inside conditionally rendered custom tag - backing bean method not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782503/fajax-inside-conditionally-rendered-custom-tag-backing-bean-method-not-invoke)
and many more, but it didn't solve my problem :(

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `#{param['view'] eq 'test'}` didn't evaluate `true` while JSF is busy processing the ajax submit. It will then also consult the `rendered`, `disabled` and `readonly` attributes once again as safeguard against hacked requests. JSF namely doesn't include the request parameters in the `<form action>` URL as generated by `<h:form>`. This matches point 5 of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183).

There are several ways to get around this.

1. Set it as a property of the view scoped bean via `<f:viewParam>`.

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="view" value="#{testBean.view}" />
   </f:metadata>
   ...
   <h:panelGroup rendered="#{testBean.view eq 'test'}">
   ```
2. Manually retain the param via `<f:param>` (you need to put it in every submit action!):

   ```
   <h:commandLink ...>
       <f:param name="view" value="#{param.view}" />
       ...
   </h:commandLink>
   ```
3. Replace `<h:form>` by [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:form>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/form) which is capable of telling JSF that it must submit the form to an URL including the request parameters:

   ```
   <o:form includeRequestParams="true">
       ...
   </o:form>
   ```

#### See also:

- [Retaining GET request query string parameters on JSF form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734230/retaining-get-request-query-string-parameters-on-jsf-form-submit/)

Comment: Thanks for help! :D
Point 2 has solved my problem. Unfortunately, points 1 and 3 didn't  work for some reason:/

Comment: I was wrong. OmniFaces form also helped;-)