# primefaces dont validate ajax rendered component

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

```
<h:form id="formEdit">
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{testView.selection}"
                     required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="noMenu" itemLabel="selectOneMenu not rendered"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="haveMenu" itemLabel="selectOneMenu rendered"/>
        <p:ajax update="formEdit"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:panel>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="conditionallyRnedered" value="#{testView.value}"
                         rendered="#{testView.selection eq 'haveMenu'}"
                         required="true">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-" noSelectionOption="true"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:panel>
    <p:messages id="messages"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Submit"/>
</h:form>
```

Component `"conditionallyRnedered"` is required, and rendered on page after i select `"haveMenu"` value in first menu. This component have only empty option and initialy its not rendered on page. If i press Submit button, then response is:

```
<partial-response><changes>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[stateless]]></update>
</changes></partial-response>
```

**There is no validation error**. If i change value of `rendered` attribute in `"conditionallyRnedered"` from `"#{testView.selection eq 'haveMenu'}"` to just `"true"`, then response is:

```
<partial-response><changes>
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[stateless]]></update>
<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"validationFailed":true}</extension></changes>
</partial-response>
```

**Validation error returned**. The questions is:

1. Why conditionally rendered component is not validated?
2. It is possible to make them validated?

**UPD**
Originally in my question is absent Bean source code, in which Bean declared as `@ViewScoped`. After read [@BalusC comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785199/primefaces-dont-validate-ajax-rendered-component#comment55365948_33787000), i try to change scope from `@ViewScoped` to `@SessionScoped`, and after that validation is working correctly. Wherein `javax.faces.ViewState` in response changed from `stateless` to some view id:

```
<update id="javax.faces.ViewState">-5902669082498843838:729675320168079573</update>
```

I still doubt, this is solution or still workaround, because I thought that instance of `@ViewScoped` bean is exist while we dont left the page. Maybe this behavior is caused by the fact that in the same page present another bean, with `@SessionScoped` scope.

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar No, the result is same. Attribute `update` is working - conditionally rendered component is showed on form after ajax request. The component `p:messages` is useless, because there is no validation errors in response, nothing to show.

Comment: i have added answer. please check if it works

Comment: why was <f:view transient="true"> added in your xhtml?

Comment: i added <f:view transient="true"> and even with my "work-around", the validation message is not working. Can you please explain why you said it works after using my solution. I am confused.

Comment: Did the people who downvoted my answer which has been mentioned as workaround even test with no <f:view transient="true"> and  have @ViewScoped like balusC mentioned and  Removed my "work-around" Still no validation message on clicking "Submit" button. only AFTER adding ajax="false" which was mentioned as "workaround", it is working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It failed for the technical reason explained in this Q&A: [Form submit in conditionally rendered component is not processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782503/form-submit-in-conditionally-rendered-component-is-not-processed). In a nutshell, JSF will re-check the `rendered` attribute during processing the form submit/conversion/validation and skip components which aren't rendered during that moment. The answer is to use a `@ViewScoped` bean.

That it still failed in spite of that you're actually using a `@ViewScoped` bean is because you're using a stateless view via `<f:view transient="true">`, as confirmed by the actual `javax.faces.ViewState` value and [What is the usefulness of statelessness in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890995/what-is-the-usefulness-of-statelessness-in-jsf) In other words, JSF won't save/restore the view, including any view scoped beans. Those beans will technically behave like `@RequestScoped` beans and thus be recreated on every request,  resetting their properties to defaults everytime.

To solve your problem, just turn off stateless view by **removing** `<f:view transient="true">` and keep your bean `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: i added <f:view transient="true"> to my page. Even with my "work-around" validation message is not coming in. Then why did the OP comment on my question saying "Thank you, this solution is works fine! – bobzer 10 hours ago". How did it work for him? I am confused why it worked for him. Can you explain, if you have some time please?

Comment: i tested with no <f:view transient="true"> and i have @ViewScoped like you mentioned. Removed my "work-around" Still no validation message on clicking "Submit" button. I do not have context param javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD in web.xml.

Comment: I tried  import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped; now without my "work-around". Still doesn't work. I am still learning,

Answer (score -1):

@bobzer,

primefaces commandButton has become ajax="true" by default. So when i set ajax="false", the form is submitted and i can see validation errors

i get [image: validation error coming]

My xhtml:

```
    <h:form id="formEdit">
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{testView.selection}" required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="noMenu"
            itemLabel="selectOneMenu not rendered" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="haveMenu" itemLabel="selectOneMenu rendered" />
        <p:ajax update="formEdit" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:panel>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="conditionallyRnedered" value="#{testView.value}"
            rendered="#{testView.selection eq 'haveMenu'}" required="true">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-"
                noSelectionOption="true" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:panel>
    <p:messages id="messages" />
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"/>
</h:form>
```

My Bean

```
        package citi.manageID.framework.admin.roleMgmt;

    import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
    import javax.inject.Named;

    @Named
    @ViewScoped
    public class TestView {


        private String selection="";

        private String value="";

        public String getSelection() {
            return selection;
        }

        public void setSelection(String selection) {
            this.selection = selection;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }


    }
```

Comment: This is not a solution. This is a workaround. Pay closer attention to `javax.faces.ViewState` value in OP's ajax response to find the real explanation and answer.

Comment: @BalusC
i added <f:view transient="true"> to my page. Even with my "work-around" validation message is not coming in. Then why did the OP comment on my question saying "Thank you, this solution is works fine! – bobzer 10 hours ago".

Comment: i tested with no <f:view transient="true"> and i have @ViewScoped like you mentioned. Removed my "work-around" Still no validation message on clicking "Submit" button. I do not have context param javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD in web.xml Did the people who downvoted even test the answer this way?

Comment: Possibly the difference is in you using the newer CDI ViewScope (javax.faces.view.ViewScoped) and the question is about the original JSF ViewScope (javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped). Impossible to tell really, the question doesn't say if CDI is used or not.

Comment: Hmmm....I tried import import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped; now. Still doesnt work. @BalusC will respond the correct solution i hope.