# Primefaces : Ajax rendered p:commandButton doesn't submit with actionListener

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have below structure for my `forgotpassword.xhtml` view.

```
<p:outputPanel id="forgotPassword" autoUpdate="true">
    <!--Accepting email address-->
    <h:form>
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{!vctrl.status &amp;&amp; !vctrl.accountLocked}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field s12">
                    <h:inputText id="emailAddress" value="#{vctrl.emailAddress}" size="35"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 btn-col">
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" styleClass="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-med" 
                        update=":forgotPassword" actionListener="#{vctrl.checkIfEmailExists}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" styleClass="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-med red darken-4"
                        immediate="true" style="float:right" action="#{vctrl.logout}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
    <!--checking for security question and answer-->
    <h:form>
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{vctrl.status &amp;&amp; !secBean.secBeanBlockDisplay &amp;&amp; !vctrl.accountLocked}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field s12">
                    <h:inputSecret id="secBeanAns1" value="#{secBean.secBeanAnswer1}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field s12">
                    <h:inputSecret id="secBeanAns2" value="#{secBean.secBeanAnswer2}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col s12 btn-col">
                    <p:outputPanel>
                        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":forgotPassword"
                            data="#{vctrl.emailAddress}"
                            actionListener="#{secBean.checksecBeanQuestionsAndResetPass}"
                            oncomplete="setFocus();showpopup();"
                            styleClass="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-med" />
                        <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
                            action="#{vctrl.logout}"
                            styleClass="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-med red darken-4"
                            immediate="true" style="float:right" />
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:outputPanel>
        <p:outputPanel rendered="#{secBean.secBeanBlockDisplay}">
            <div id="reloginpopup" class="modal" style="top: 35%">
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </h:form>
</p:outputPanel>
```

Once the user enters his email address, next ajax view within 2nd form will be displayed. But the button inside this rendered `element` doesn't submit as expected. It doesn't hit the `actionListner` method - `checksecBeanQuestionsAndResetPass` at all. It just reloads the page and renders `forgotPassword` initial view.

My question is, will or not `p:commandButton` work when rendered through `ajax`? I went through **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-find-out-client-id-of-component-for-ajax-update-render-cannot-find-compo)** and as per the answer there, `p:commandButton` should be included within already rendered element. For me its the `form` which will be `rendered` initially, within which am loading the rest of the contents for security questions. So this should behave as expected. But am totally out of ideas as in why this is not calling bean method. Anything else to be configured here?

**Edit**

I've also added `@ManagedBean` and `@RequestScoped` to my `beans`.

---

**Update**

So after visiting **[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value/2120183#2120183)**, **[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)**, **[post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782503/form-submit-in-conditionally-rendered-component-is-not-processed)** etc., still I couldn't get this working. My `bean` method is never called at all. Below is how I've updated my `commandButton` within `rendered` html

```
<p:commandButton value="Submit" immediate="true"
    update=":forgotPassword"
    actionListener="#{secBean.checkSecurityQuestionsAndResetPass}"
    process="@this"
    data="#{vctrl.emailAddress}"
    styleClass="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-med" />
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true"
    actionListener="#{vctrl.logout}"
    styleClass="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-med red darken-4"
    style="float:right"/>
```

and my bean method is as below:

```
public void checkSecurityQuestionsAndResetPass(ActionEvent event) {
        String emailAddress = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes()
                .get("data");
        //some processing
}
```

Any other ways I can try to get this to work?

Comment: add id to form and buttons

Comment: @Abihabi87 I just added ids to `form` and `buttons` but no luck buddy..

Comment: Did you try to call your listener via <f:ajax>?

Comment: No, I didn't tried that @dsp_user.. Let me try once..